# Geoserver 2.17.2 WFS-T and WPS

Tags: javascript, geoserver

I cannot manage to run WFS-T demos in GeoServer 2.17.2. In Demo always give an error. In a similar way, I want to run WPS demos but always got an error

> coverage store not found

In the workspace I enabled WPS but I got no response coming from geoserver side.

> HTTP response: 500 Server Error

Anyone know how can I run WFS-T demos in GeoServer ?

```
// Promises 
var _eid_promises = {};
// Turn the incoming message from extension // into pending Promise resolving 
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    if (event.source !== window) return;
    if (event.data.src && (event.data.src === "background.js")) {
        console.log("Page received: ");
        console.log(event.data);
        // Get the promise 
        if (event.data.nonce) {
            var p = _eid_promises[event.data.nonce];
            // resolve 
            if (event.data.result === "ok") {
                if (event.data.signature !== undefined) {
                    p.resolve({
                        hex: event.data.signature
                    });
                } else if (event.data.version !== undefined) {
                    p.resolve(event.data.extension + "/" + event.data.version);
                } else if (event.data.cert !== undefined) {
                    p.resolve({
                        hex: event.data.cert
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("No idea how to handle message");
                    console.log(event.data);
                }
            } else { // reject 
                p.reject(new Error(event.data.result));
            }
            delete _eid_promises[event.data.nonce];
        } else {
            console.log("No nonce in event msg");
        }
    }
}, false);

function TokenSigning() {
    function nonce() {
        var val = "";
        var hex = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) val += hex.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length));
        return val;
    }

    function messagePromise(msg) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { // amend with necessary metadata
            msg["nonce"] = nonce();
            msg["src"] = "page.js";
            // send message 
            window.postMessage(msg, "*");
            // and store promise 
            callbacks _eid_promises[msg.nonce] = {
                resolve: resolve,
                reject: reject
            };
        });
    }
    this.getCertificate = function (options) {
        var msg = {
            type: "CERT",
            lang: options.lang,
            filter: options.filter
        };
        console.log("getCertificate()");
        return messagePromise(msg);
    };
    this.sign = function (cert, hash, options) {
        var msg = {
            type: "SIGN",
            cert: cert.hex,
            hash: hash.hex,
            hashtype: hash.type,
            lang: options.lang,
            info: options.info
        };
        console.log("sign()");
        return messagePromise(msg);
    };
    this.getVersion = function () {
        console.log("getVersion()");
        return messagePromise({
            type: "VERSION"
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: what does the log file say? Try turning the logging level upto GeoTools Developer and trying again

Comment: Hi Ian, Finally I found the problem in WPS. We have to give coordinates according to native coordinate system. Finally I can succeed to take tif. I will try with them time filter. But WFS-T gives magic number expected error in logs. But when I upgrade my Geoserver to 2.20 it has worked. Thanks a lot.